# DBSet<> not working on .net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to ask for help on returning DBSet<> on .net core WEB API.

Here is my code on the ADO.NET Entity Model DBSet tbl_employee :

```
public virtual DbSet<tbl_employee> tbl_employee { get; set; }
```

I am having an error on this code (.Net Core) :

```
return db.tbl_employee.ToList();
```

This is the error : 
[image]

But on my MVC 5 project :

```
return db.tbl_employee.ToList();
```

This does not return any error on DBSet on my MVC 5 Web API project. How could the MVC5 version does not return any error but returns on .NET Core?

I installed "EntityFramework" package on the MVC 5 project. But I cannot install "EntityFramework" on .Net Core project. Upon researching, I found out that "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" is the EF for .net core.

I think it's about the nuget package but I can't figure out which version / package should I install.

I would highly appreciate suggestions / comments. Thank you in advance and have a great day!

Comment: *“How could the MVC5 version does not return any error but returns on .NET Core?”* – How can an error appear in one project but in a completely different project using a completely different framework, it does not appear?! Read the error message, you haven’t referenced EntityFramework correctly.

Comment: @poke Hi Sir, first of all thank you for your response. I installed "EntityFramework" package on the MVC 5 project. But I cannot install "EntityFramework" on .Net Core project. Upon researching, I found out that "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" is the EF for .net core. I think it's about the EF nuget package but I can't figure out which version / package should I install.

Comment: But EntityFramework and EntityFrameworkCore are also incompatible. It seems that the library you’re referencing (`Biometrics.API`) has a reference on EntityFramework 6, so you would need to fulfill that requirement in order to use it. However, EF6 does not run on .NET Core (it can run on ASP.NET Core when targetting the full .NET Framework). So with your current setup, you cannot use your library. – Please note that ASP.NET (MVC 5) and ASP.NET Core are fundamentally different, so you cannot really mix them with each other.

Comment: @poke your statement is the answer to my question. Thank you sir!